# Reading data with firebase and vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vue-cli-3

I'm not very experienced, and I was wondering how I can extract data from firebase, updating the status element of vue.js. The problem is that I can not extract the fusion data dedicated to firebase "snapshot".
I leave you all the code and all the errors below.

Vue.js code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

      <div>
        <h1>ON/OFF led</h1>
        <h2>Status: {{ device.status() }}</h2>
      </div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

import { deviceStatusRef } from './firebase';

var pinReport;


export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      device: {
        nome: 'led',
        status: function(){
              deviceStatusRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                pinReport = snapshot.val();
                console.log("[1] - pinReport value --> " + pinReport);
              });
              console.log("[2] - pinReport VALUE --> " + pinReport);
              return pinReport;
            }
      }
    }
  },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Errors on Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `[2]` log statement runs, the data hasn't been loaded yet and `pinReport` is undefined.

This means that all code that needs the data must be inside the callback, like your `[1]` log statement. It also means that you can't return the value from the database from a function, since the `return` runs before the data is loaded.

Comment: ok, how can I solve this problem? Do you have any advice on correctly displaying the status data of vue.js

Comment: I was reading up on that. It seems that in Vue you can just set a property of the component and Vue will rerender it. See https://frontendsociety.com/transitioning-from-react-to-vue-c9aa943bd0da#be71

Comment: I did some tests but the problem persists

Comment: when I'm inside the callback I can not recall the props of vue.js

Comment: maybe I found a way, look this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-can-i-get-the-data-returned-by-callback-function/18433

Comment: My explanation is why your current code can't work. But what you shared has nothing to do with Vue yet. Since your problem now is with vue, update your question to include the minimum complete code that shows how you're *now* trying to update the view.

Comment: As you can see in the forum post you linked, their code just updates a property and it Vue uses that to rerender the component.

Comment: I have just updated the code, my goal and view the status of a LED in real time